# How does a computer solve matrices of higher order?

Tags: algorithms

To compute the determinant of a $n \times n$ matrix using the cofactor expansion requires roughly $n!$ operations ($n! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \ldots \times n)$.
Consider a $25 \times 25$ matrix. This would require $25!$ operations or roughly operations. Suppose you have a super computer that can do $1$ trillion operations per second. This calculation would require $500,000$ years!!
How do you find the determinant of $25 \times 25$ matrix then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation ​ ​

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are other algorithms that can be used to calculate the determinant. The simplest ones find a triangular matrix similar to the given matrix. Since similar matrices have the same determinant, this reduces the general determinant question to triangular matrices, for which the computation is trivial (multiply the elements on the diagonal). This algorithm takes $O(n^3)$ practically (using LU decomposition), or $O(n^\omega)$ theoretically, where $\omega$ is the exponent of matrix multiplication.

From a theoretical perspective there are other non-trivial methods for computing the determinant, described [on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/12452/40).